# Pull specific value from $http angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mapbox-gl

Web API is connected and working fine, fetching and showing the data properly.
now need to show the map(map box) with specific coordination through API

**JS**

```
function frmccode() {
  var path_cc = api + vm.ccode;

  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: path_cc,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + bearer.token
    }
  }).then(function(resp) {
    $scope.itemsc = resp.data;
  }).catch(function(err) {
    $scope.err = err.status;
    if ($scope.err === 404) {
      $scope.ccerror = err.status;
    }
  });
}

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  zoom: 6,
  center: [54, 24],
  container: 'map',
  style: 'http://abcd.com/api/gis/style',
});
```

**HTML**

```
  <table class="table">
    <tbody ng-repeat="item in itemsc">
      <tr>
        <div id="map" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>GPS</th>
        <td>Latitude: {{item.latitude}} | Longitude: {{item.longitude}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**web API**

```
"latitude": {},
"longitude": {}
```

Lat/Long. is showing fine in HTML,
but how can pull lat/long. from  **resp.data* and pass it in the map function?

Comment: Move your `var map = ...` statement up into the `then` callback. In there, your data is available

Comment: @Phil, yes, but I m not getting how to catch item with value i.e **$scope.itemsc.latitude** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value is in Array.
should be like this ....

```
var lat = resp.data[0].latitude;
```

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1):

I would turn the map into a directive. Something like:

```
myDirectives.directive('myMap', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: { lat: '=', long: '='},
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        //lat long available here (2 way binding)
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
          zoom: 6,
          center: [54, 24],
          container: attrs.container,
          style: 'http://abcd.com/api/gis/style',
        });

      }
    };
  });
```

And you can use it like this

```
  <table class="table">
    <tbody ng-repeat="item in itemsc">
      <tr>
        <div my-map id="map" container="map" lat="item.latitude" long="item.longitude" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>GPS</th>
        <td>Latitude: {{item.latitude}} | Longitude: {{item.longitude}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it inside function callback. Loop through itemsc,

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.className = 'marker';
el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + img_url + ')';


new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat([item.lng, item.lat])
    .addTo(map);
```